# Difference between seed and pump in chirped pulse amplifier

Tags: optics, laser, fiber-optics, optical-materials, laser-cavity

What is the difference between to seed an optical amplifier (such as  Chirped Pulse Amplifier) and to pump it with a laser source?

Comment: What does CPA mean? Or did you mean OPA (optical parametric amplifier)?

Comment: @flippiefanus CPA stands for Chirped Pulse Amplifier

Comment: Write it out in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seed is the signal that the amplifier amplifies. To control the output, you control the seed. The pump provides the power to the amplifier.

Comment: is it true that the pump creates the population inversion, and then the seed is amplified by stimulated emission?

Comment: @Soun Yes, that's how a laser works. Some seed themselves with spontaneous emission, though.